# Bind por posição em SQL Server utilizando Node JS (MSSQL)

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, sql-server, node.js

Gostaria de saber se é possível realizar o bind dos parâmetros por posição ao invés do nome utilizando mssql em NodeJS.

Ex.:

```
//Por nome
return pool.request()
.input('input_parameter1', sql.Int, 10)
.input('input_parameter2', sql.Int, 20)
.query('select * from mytable where id = @input_parameter1 and valor = @input_parameter2')
```

O que preciso seria algo do tipo:

```
//Por posição
return pool.request()
.query('select * from mytable where id = ? and valor = ?', [10, 20], 
function(err, result){
console.log("Resultado: " + result);
});
```

Comment: Tenha cuidado em alterar a forma de consulta, pois no primeiro código o "mssql" implementa uma proteção contra SQLi. Veja aqui: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#sql-injection

Comment: @MarceloJunior se souberes uma alternativa de resolver isto melhor que a minha coloca uma resposta, eu não conheço a biblioteca por isso pode haver maneiras melhores.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @MarceloJunior, não tinha pensado nisso....

Comment: @Sergio também não conheço, procurei alternativas para ajudar na resposta e não achei nada que já tenha sido implementado.

Comment: @LucasSouza Por nada :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar dessa maneira com o [`mysql` (link)](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql). A ideia é como mostras no código, usar marcadores `?` na query e depois passar uma array com as posições cujo valor deve ser usado em vez do marcador.

Segundo o exemplo da documentação:

```
connection.query('UPDATE users SET foo=?, bar=?, baz=? WHERE id=?', ['a', 'b', 'c', userId], (error, results, fields) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  // ...
});
```

Para implementar isso no mssql podias fazer o teu próprio wrapper:

```js
const superQuery = (conn, query, values) => {
  let req = pool.request();
  let value = values.shift();
  let counter = 1;

  while (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
    let sep = 'input_parameter' + (counter++);
    req = req.input(sep, value);
    query = query.replace('?', '@' + sep);
    value = values.shift()
  }
  return req.query(query);
}
```

E depois usares assim:

```
superQuery(
    connection, 
    'UPDATE users SET foo=?, bar=?, baz=? WHERE id=?', 
    ['a', 'b', 'c', userId]
).then(res => {
    ...etc
});
```

**Nota:** o `mssql` tem um conceito de protótipos como segundo argumento opcional de `. input()`. Seria simples incorporar isso no meu wrapper para não se perder esse nivel de segurança. Porem a array passada em vez de simples seria um objeto com o prototipo também.

Comment: Então, com o mysql eu vi que tem como.. Só que meu banco é o mssql, sabe se tem como usar por posição nele, como no mysql? Os marcadores podem alterar, isso não tem problema, se for o caso, tipo @ID... Só que queria por posição do que por nome na hora de fazer o bind...

Comment: @LucasSouza desculpa, não reparei no `mssql`! Tentei redimir-me com uma sugestão de solução :)

Comment: Obrigado! Estou fazendo o wrapper conforme comentou para manter a segurança

Comment: Funcionou como vc falou e mantive a segurança que o mssql utiliza..

Comment: @LucasSouza ótimo!